# Mantaflow explosion looks nothing like the tutorial

Tags: particles, mantaflow

So recently I was looking into making explosions in Blender with Mantaflow, and I was following a tutorial by Iridesium but my explosion looked nothing like his. I followed it step by step, but when I would baked it there was no complex fire or smoke. I am using Blender 2.91, and tried both Cycles and Eevee renderers. This is what his explosion looked like at one of the earlier steps:

[image: Blender explosion image from Iredesium in one of his tutorials]

and this is what mine looked like:

[image: Bad explosion in blender]

I also followed a few other tutorials, and my explosions always just looked like the particle lines and then some smoke, with none of the bubbles or explosion-looking effect. How do I get mine to look like the tutorials?

If you need any more info I can post screenshots, I'm pretty sure my settings are the same and I followed his steps. I also did some other tutorials, and mine all look way different from what theirs look like.

Comment: Firstly I've never used mantaflow, but I see that the tutorial you're following was done in Blender 2.82 so if you're using a recent version there may well have been changes in the settings you need to use to get the same effect. See https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/79029 for instance.